# How to get fetch data for the current financial year in oracle sql developer grouping by year and month?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to fetch monthwise total amount for the current financial year and the last financial year . I cannot hard code the date . It should be based on the current date .The date column is in the following format 13-JAN-10 
and amount is in integer format.

**I want it in the following format :**

```
Month       2016-17   2017-18

June         17890    50980
July         45900    14879
August
September
October
November
December
January
February
March 
April
May
```

I couldnt move past the current query i wrote

```
SELECT
   CASE WHEN MONTH(sysdate)>=7 THEN
          concat(YEAR(sysdate), '-',YEAR(sysdate)+1)
   ELSE concat(YEAR(sysdate)-1,'-', YEAR(sysdate)) END AS financial_year,
   SUM(AMOUNT)
FROM TABLE a
GROUP BY financial_year ;
```

Comment: Do not use tags for products are not involved

Comment: Alright jen thanks , will keep in mind next time .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Group By - counting records per month/year, error on insert - NOT A VALID MONTH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11438806/sql-group-by-counting-records-per-month-year-error-on-insert-not-a-valid-mo)

Comment: @goonernike You said **The date column is in the following format 13-JAN-10** Well, that's wrong, because `DATE` doesn't have any format. The format you see is just to display it in your locale specific NLS settings. Now, coming back to your required output, you need to provide working test case, i.e. CREATE TABLE, INSERT STATEMENTS, the rules to achieve the output and desired output.

Comment: Why do you use `sysdate` everywhere? It is a function which returns a current date and time. Maybe you need a name of a column with date here?

Comment: There is no `month()` or `year()` function in Oracle, nor is there a `concat()` function that accepts three parameters. Are you sure you are use an Oracle database? (Oracle SQL Developer is not a database product, it's a SQL client that can connect to several different DBMS products)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't checked my date arithmetic too seriously, but hopefully this example will give you an idea for how you can tackle it

Setting up some test data:

```
SQL> exec dbms_random.seed(0)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

--
-- 1000 random dates and values
--
SQL> create table t as
  2  select date '2016-01-01' + trunc(dbms_random.value(1,800)) dte,
  3        rownum amount
  4  from dual
  5  connect by level <= 1000;

Table created.

--
-- sample data at the extrema
--

SQL>
SQL> select * from t
  2  order by 1
  3  fetch first 10 rows only;

DTE           AMOUNT
--------- ----------
02-JAN-16        562
03-JAN-16        486
04-JAN-16        843
05-JAN-16        661
06-JAN-16        255
06-JAN-16        382
07-JAN-16         31
07-JAN-16        506
07-JAN-16        290
07-JAN-16        185

10 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> select * from t
  2  order by 1 desc
  3  fetch first 10 rows only;

DTE           AMOUNT
--------- ----------
10-MAR-18        978
09-MAR-18        262
08-MAR-18        295
07-MAR-18         33
06-MAR-18        469
03-MAR-18        454
03-MAR-18        593
03-MAR-18        538
02-MAR-18        226
02-MAR-18        928

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Here's the query. `fin_start` defines the start of the fin year (because its not June for everyone :-))

```
SQL> with fin_start as
  2   ( select date '2017-06-01' fs from dual )
  3  select mth, last_fin_year, this_fin_year
  4  from (
  5  select
  6    to_char(dte,'Month') mth,
  7    to_char(dte,'MM') mth_seq,
  8    fin_start.fs,
  9    sum(case when dte between add_months(fin_start.fs,-112) and fin_start.fs-1 then amount end) last_fin_year,
 10    sum(case when dte between fin_start.fs and add_months(fin_start.fs,12)-1 then amount end) this_fin_year
 11  from t, fin_start
 12  group by
 13    to_char(dte,'Month'),
 14    to_char(dte,'MM'),
 15    fin_start.fs
 16  )
 17  order by
 18    case when mth_seq >= to_char(fs,'MM') then 1 else 2 end,
 19    mth_seq;

MTH                                  LAST_FIN_YEAR THIS_FIN_YEAR
------------------------------------ ------------- -------------
June                                         20658         22188
July                                         13267          8844
August                                       15907         20457
September                                    15140         21906
October                                      21850         15100
November                                     18153         21052
December                                     14111         14677
January                                      44159         23112
February                                     43819         14267
March                                        50641          5047
April                                        37397
May                                          38748

12 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any clues about what columns you have in your "a" table. So, in my answer I assume that you have some YOURTABLE table where you have some transactions (orders) rows. And in these rows you have YOURTABLE.YOURDATE date as an order date and YOURTABLE.YOURAMOUNT as order amount.

All you need to group your order sums by months is:

```
group by trunc(t.YOURDATE, 'mm')
```

But if you want to want to represent these groups as 2 columns like in your example, you should make 2 selects (for past year and current year) from YOURTABLe. and then join them. Here is the example:

```
with curryear as
 (select to_char(trunc(t.YOURDATE, 'mm'), 'month') dmonth,
         sum(t.YOURAMOUNT) dresults
    from YOURTABLE t
   group by trunc(t.YOURDATE, 'mm')
  having trunc(t.YOURDATE, 'mm') >= '01-JUL-2017'
   order by trunc(t.YOURDATE, 'mm') asc),
pastyear as
 (select to_char(trunc(t.YOURDATE, 'mm'), 'month') dmonth,
         sum(t.YOURAMOUNT) dresults
    from YOURTABLE t
   group by trunc(t.YOURDATE, 'mm')
  having trunc(t.YOURDATE, 'mm') between '01-JUL-2016' and '01-JUN-2017'
   order by trunc(t.YOURDATE, 'mm') asc)
select curryear.dmonth   "Month",
       pastyear.dresults    "2016-17",
       curryear.dresults "2017-18"
  from curryear, pastyear
 where curryear.dmonth = pastyear.dmonth;
```

Hope this helps!